# scss for loop renders percentage wierd

Tags: css, ruby, sass, middleman

I'm trying to make a responsive design that flips from horizontal to vertical depending on the screen width and I need all the widths in percentage defined in css because I cannot use JavaScript.

The app is based on `Middleman` (a ruby gem) and I use `scss` as the `css` processor/renderer.

For this in `scss`:

```
@for $i from 0 through 100 {
    .width-percentage-#{$i} {
      width : #{percentage($i/100)};
    }
}
```

It gets this in `css` :

```
... 
.width-percentage-27 {
    width: 27%
}
.width-percentage-28 {
    width: 28.0%
}
.width-percentage-29 {
    width: 29.0%
}
.width-percentage-30 {
    width: 30%
}
...

.width-percentage-53 {
    width: 53%
}
.width-percentage-54 {
    width: 54%
}
.width-percentage-55 {
    width: 55.0%
}
.width-percentage-56 {
    width: 56.0%
}
.width-percentage-57 {
    width: 57.0%
}
.width-percentage-58 {
    width: 58.0%
}
.width-percentage-59 {
    width: 59%
}
...
```

Now notice the problem ... for `28`, `29`,`55`, `56`, `57`, `58` there is a `.0` in the value.

The browsers I'm targeting are handling this fine. But how does scss processor renders somehow different value types (int and floats) in the same loop ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strange indeed you could solve this issue by using `round` or `ceil`

```
@for $i from 0 through 100 {
  .width-percentage-#{$i} {
    width : round(percentage($i/100));
  }
}
```

An example: http://sassmeister.com/gist/2c6f6b7cd825b16e423a

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add `%` symbol to 100 to make the operation work.

```
@for $i from 1 through 100 {
  .width-percentage-#{$i} {
    width : #{100% / $i};
  }
}
```